# Engine routes in Application Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing, rails-engines

I have a before_filter hook in my main app's application controller that does something like: (It doesn't just put a link in the flash, there is a message, but it isn't relevant to the question, it just accesses the route in the method)

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_link

  def set_link
    flash[:notice] = items_path
  end
end
```

This works fine for the app, however when I go into the controllers for an engine I made I get the exception

```
No route matches {:controller=>"items", :action=>"index"}
```

I understand that when in the engine, the routes helpers are for the engine unless prefixed with `main_app`

So changing the method in the application controller to

```
  def set_link
    flash[:notice] = main_app.items_path
  end
```

Gets rid of the exception but I really don't want to have to do that. Is there another solution to getting the engine to recognize the main_app routes?

EDIT:

This also happens if the application layout calls path helpers. So if the engine is designed to integrated into the main_app's layout then this issue will crop there up too.

Comment: What's wrong with `main_app`? Besides that, why you're introducing a dependency in your engine from the main app, in this way your engine depends on `items_path` being defined in **every** app which uses it. This is not a good practice, usually you should use only `main_app.root_path`, or some other well known routes (for instance if your using devise the `sign_in_path`).

Comment: items_path would be defined in the main app which is already built. And I want to have the engine mounted somewhere but integrated into the current app's layout. The engine itself never references items_path at all. 
I just want the views generated by the engine to get put in the body of the application layout. However, the application layout needs to access to the main_app's routes

Comment: This comes from the need to have the engine and the application share the same layout. That way when a user goes from a page on the main app, to a page on the engine, there is no visible difference between the layout.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Mountable engines are designed to work like this, that is isolate the main app routes and the engine routes.

If you want the two sets of routes to be merged, you can use a non-isolated engine. The first step is removing the `isolated_namespace` method call in your engine definition:

```
module MyEngine
  class Engine < Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace MyEngine # remove this line
  end
end
```

The second step is to convert your routes in `my_engine/config/routes.rb`, you should go from this:

```
MyEngine::Engine.routes.draw do
  # stuff that routes things
end
```

to this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # stuff that routes things
end
```

and remove the `mount` method call in your application's routes:

```
App::Application.routes.draw do
  mount MyEngine::Engine => "/engine" # remove this line
end
```

The main advantages of doing it this way would be:

1. No need to monkey-patch rails. I know devise does this, but this could be a leftover from the days when engines didn't exist in rails.
2. No need to mount the engine in the application routes. On the other hand, this could backfire if you'd like to control more precisely the insertion point as all you engine routes would be called after (or before, I don't have the answer to this question) your main routes.

If you're looking for documentation on engines, the [rails docs for the Engine class](http://apidock.com/rails/Rails/Engine) are a pretty good starting point. I'd strongly recommend that you read them (in case you haven't yet) if you're interested in the subject.

Comment: you forgot to note, if you remove `isolated_namespace` you might expose yourself to some name conflicts with the main app or other gems (example: helpers)

Answer (score 4):

I figured out how to do this. The problems lies within the isolated namespace. In order to integrate the engine with the app and share the same layout (which may have path helpers from the main app) I did this:

Firstly I removed `config/routes.rb` from the engine

Then I removed the isolate_namespace from the engine class

```
module MyEngine
   class Engine < Rails::Engine
-    isolate_namespace MyEngine
   end
 end
end
```

I added a file that was loaded in the engine:

```
module ActionDispatch::Routing
  class Mapper
    def mount_my_engine_at(mount_location)
      scope mount_location do
        #Declare all your routes here
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Finally, in the main app's `config/routes.rb` instead of 'mount'ing the engine, you can call your method

```
mount_my_engine_at "mount_location"
```

This will basically 'mount' your engine as part of the main app instead of being isolated from it. It is similar to how Devise does it too.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep the isolate_namespace.
In your engine routes.rb

```
MyEngine::Engine.routes.draw do
  ...
  root to: "something#index"
end

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get "something", to: "my_engine/something#index"
end
```

And then in the main app routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  mount MyEngine::Engine => "/anything_you_want"

  root to: "main#index"
end
```

This way you can choose what routes you want to expose (and which you do not)

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the isolate_namespace, as strongly recommended by Rails Engine guide, and do this:

```
# inside your main_app's config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'home#index'

  mount MyEngine::Engine, at: "/" 
end
```

```
# inside your engine's controller
module MyEngine
  class SomeController << ::ApplicationController
    # include main_app's route helpers
    helper Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  end
end
```

And inside your gem, make sure all the url helpers are prefixed with the correct routing proxy method (e.g. my_engine.pages_path).

Your main_app's layout and engine's controller will route and link to those url helpers correctly to the main app. You don't have to add "main_app" prefix anywhere to the main app. The only downside is you're mounting your engine's routes at main_app's root path, which could collide with any routes by the same name. This is expected anyway if you were to do non-isolate_namespace.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to draw the routes in both the main app, and the engine, so that they are accessible to both:

```
[MyEngine::Engine, App::Application].each do |app|
  app.routes.draw do
    # Declare all your routes here
  end
end
```