# Accessing application helpers from RailsEngine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

I have Rails application with mounted Engine.

```
#{main_app}/config/routes.rb
mount CommentIt::Engine => "/talk", :as => 'comment_it'
```

And want to open engine views within main application layout.

```
#{main_app}/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<html>
  <body>
    <%= link_to "users", users_path %>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

When accessing engine views(0.0.0.0:3000/talk) I got error **'undefined method `users_path' for #<#:0x007f9dbf0f7800>'**
users_path works fine in main application views. 
How I get route helpers from main application, when accessing Engine pages?

Comment: I have this exact same problem. Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: Update: seems to be impossible with a mountable engine. It can only be done using a full engine (without an isolated namespace). See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Rails 3.2 the only way to do this is convert your engine into a 'full' engine and not a mountable engine. In mountable engines, the engine has no knowledge of the host application and its path/url helpers are not accessible by default.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588870/engine-routes-in-application-controller#answer-7622755) explains what needs to be done, which worked for me.

The alternative is to traverse the host application's files and include the proper view/application helpers into your engine. It works, but for me it was too much of a hassle. Simply converting to a full engine did the trick.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not yet sure how (un)wise this might be, but have just found the following to work for a mountable/isolated engine I'm working on:

```
# in app/helpers/my_engine/application_helper.rb
module MyEngine
  module ApplicationHelper
    def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
      main_app.send(method, *args, &block)
    rescue NoMethodError
      super
    end
  end
end
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Not a very good idea, since it breaks the isolation of the engine from the application. That means you're back to a web of dependencies instead of a nice tree. It also means you likely can't extract the engine as a gem. What's the point of using an engine if you do this?

Comment: main_app was what I was looking for thanks.  I'm having to customize stuff I get from an engine, so it's appropriate to use main_app in there, since the view lives within the app but is inserted into the engine.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access engine helpers from the main application, you can use the name that you created for the app when you mounted it.

In config/routes.rb in your main application:

```
MyApplication::Application.routes.draw do
  mount MyEngine::Engine => "/some_engine", :as => "some_engine"
  get "/path_i_want_to_reference_from_main_app" => "some_controller#some_action"
end
```

Inside main application controllers/views:

```
some_engine.path_i_want_to_reference_from_main_app_path
```

So in your case you would use:

```
<%= link_to "users", comment_it.users_path %>
```

If you want to access main application helpers from an engine, try `main_app.users_path`

http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html

Comment: The matter in that 'users_path' already calling from main application layout (. Rewriting main app isn't good idea, it already has thousands helpers in views. I trying to use Engine views under main application layout(with main app helpers in it).

Comment: I see, I misunderstood your question, edited my answer to address that case as well

Comment: Thank for help. But I don't want access engine helpers from main app and not main app helpers from engine ). I want to get work main app helpers in main app layouts when layouts using in engine views. For ex. www.site.com - main app - works fine. Standalone engine with his own layout works fine too. www.site.com/talk - Engine within main app layout(see ex. above) crash with error (.

Comment: In other words I want to work with main app helpers inside Engine without modify that helpers. Because they used in main app layout and I don't always have control over main app layouts.

Comment: Ah, ok.  I'm sorry I don't know how to do that.  I would recommend taking a peek at the Rails code for how it resolves helpers, that might give you a clue on how to do this.  Please share the solution if you find it.

Answer (score 2):

To access main app helpers (ApplicationHelper) from engine's views I tried include this:

**app/helpers/your_engine/application_helper.rb**

```
module YourEngine
  module ApplicationHelper
    include ActionView::Helpers::ApplicationHelper
  end
end
```

It works, but once, when I restarted dev server, it throws me `uninitialized constant ActionView::Helpers::ApplicationHelper`, but I can't reproduce this exception.

**EDIT**

Removed this `include` and made this one:

**lib/my_engine/engine.rb** (it's inside engine)

```
module MyEngine
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace MyEngine
    config.to_prepare do
      ApplicationController.helper(ActionView::Helpers::ApplicationHelper)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case i had `MyCustomEngineController` inside my gem, which inherited `ApplicationController`, like so:

```
module MyEngine
  class MyCustomEngineController < ApplicationController

#...
```

i changed this inheritance a little bit:

```
module MyEngine
  class MyCustomEngineController < ::ApplicationController

#...
```

(notice `::` before `ApplicationController`)

and now all my app's helpers are available for my engine's views