# Override host app's root route from Mountable Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-engines

I'm writing a mountable Rails 3 Engine, and I am combining my engine's routes with the host app's. However, the host app's routes are taking precedence over my engine's routes. Is there a way I can override the host app's routes (specifically the root route)?

Here's my engine's routes in `my_enging/config/routes.rb`:

```
MyEngine::Engine.routes.draw do
 root :to => "home#index"
end

# Mount engine routes to host application
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount MyEngine::Engine, :at => "/"
end
```

And here's the results of `rake routes`, with the host's root sitting at the top:

```
root  / welcome#index
my_engine  / MyEngine::Engine
root  / home#index
```

[Spree](https://github.com/spree/spree) is one gem that does this, but I haven't been able to find how they're implementation this.

Answer (score 0):

People are more likely to do an opposite thing, so I can't figure out why you need this, because ability to override engine routes is supposed to be expected. Actually I have no answer how to force engine to override application routes, but:

Spree is adding routes dynamically somehow via [eval_block](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/RouteSet/eval_block), I presume.

You can just skip `root to:` as well as all undesired routes in your application at all, and then Engine routes will emerge. Do not keep them both. I don't see root specified in your application, but **I've just run an experiment and everything works!**

```
W12::Engine.routes.draw do
  root to: 'details#index'
end

MyCarsApplication.routes.draw do
  mount Common::Engine => "/"
end
```

And there is only one route:

```
root / details#index
```

[This post about creating not isolated engines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588870/engine-routes-in-application-controller) also might help.

If you found the exact answer, please post it.